# can't get response from websocket rxjs node Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket

Trying to get a WebSocket working using rxjs webSocket

I set up a node server, that throws no errors at the moment, but it doesn't send messages to the server or connected users

It seems to work better when I use 'ws://echo.websocket.org/', I see messages echoed back to me, however, I don't see messages sent, in other open browsers, basically no communication between users, that are supposed to be subscribed to the websocket

All I want is a simple way of carrying simple info between users

index.js

```
var express = require('express');


var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

var app2 = express()//There is already another app var for main app server
var server2 = http.createServer(app2);
var server2 = app2.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8081');
})


  wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server2,
  autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {

  if (origin === 'http://localhost:1234'){
    return true;

  }
// put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.

}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

  if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
    // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
    request.reject();
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
    return;
  }

  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    // console.log(message)
      if (message.type === 'utf8') {
          console.log('Received Message from: ' + connection.remoteAddress);
          connection.sendUTF(message.utf8Data);
      }
      else if (message.type === 'binary') {
          console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
          connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
      }
  });
  connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
      console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
  });
});
```

in my clientside socket service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  socket$ = Observable.webSocket( 'ws://localhost:8081');
  // 'ws://echo.websocket.org/'
  constructor() {
      this.connectToSocket()
   }

  connectToSocket(){
    this.socket$.subscribe(
      (message) => console.log('message received: ' + message),
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );
  }


}
```

And to send message, from another component, I use:

this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify('test'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of `WebSocket-Node` (https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/docs/WebSocketServer.md), you have to programatically accept each connection before continuing the handshake.

You can instead set the `autoAcceptConnections` option of your server config to `true`, like this:

```
const wss = new WebSocketServer({ httpServer: server2, autoAcceptConnections: true });
```

If you do indeed have custom request checking requirements, you can use either `accept` or `reject` inside your `request` handler, like this:

```
request.accept('chosen-protocol', 'accepted-origin')
```

or

```
request.reject()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, using the docs that you provided I got it working and have updated my question, the only problem I'm having now is if I open 2 browsers, the messages don't get broadcast between them, how do I get to test this with multiple windows?

Comment: Each browser has its own connection, so you have to keep track of them, e.g. by putting each connection in an array on connect. Then, if someone sends a message, loop over each connection in your array and send the message back. WebSocket does not broadcast out-of-the-box.

Comment: I see, thanks again, you've made things a lot clearer